# How to order AbstractControl FormArray alphabetically Angular

Tags: angular, sorting, formarray

I'm a beginner in Angular. I'm trying to sort a dropdown FormArray alphabetically.

component.html

```
<label 
    class="custom-control custom-checkbox" 
    *ngFor="let car of carsControls; let i = index" 
    [hidden]="!cars[i]?.show">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [formControl]="car" />
        <span class="custom-control-label" [innerHTML]="cars[i]?.name"></span>
</label>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cars.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
}
```

This orders the labels of the dropdown list but not the carsControl. So it is not working correctly. I don't know how to order AbstractControl alphabetically. Or do I have to sort carsFormGroup?

EDIT:

I am getting the Controls like this:

```
get carsControls() {
    return (this.carFormGroup?.get('cars') as 
    FormArray)?.controls;
  }
```

FormGroup:

```
 carFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    filter: [''],
    cars: this.formBuilder.array([])
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if I could see how you define your `carsControls` variable and the `cars` variable to make my answer more complete.

I would use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get each control name from the `FormGroup` and sort them. Then I'd iterate them in the template.

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  get controls(){
    //Object.keys() will return each form control name
    //Then sort them alphabetically 
    return Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).sort();
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit(){
    //Define my form - note how they're not alphabetical
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      "car": new FormControl(false),
      "dinosaur": new FormControl(false),
      "ant": new FormControl(false)
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<!-- The controls must live inside a form -->
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
enter code here

  <!-- iterate each control name -->
  <div *ngFor="let ctrl of controls">

    <!-- Use any kind of input you want here! -->
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="ctrl">
    <label>{{ctrl}}</label>

  </div>
</form>
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgzeti) demonstrating how this works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Please have a look on my edited post. I couldn't figure out yet how to sort the FormArray. I don't know if object.keys will work here

Comment: A `FormArray` will contain zero or more `FormGroups`. Can you also include what the array of "cars" will look like? Right now your post just has an empty array. I'm also a little unclear of why you need a FormArray at all. Is the intention to allow users to add/remove cars and then have them automatically sorted based on their name?